# Return both result of array and single row in json data from php, mysql and show in android studio

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have created a recycler view with its adapter which returns the details in my sql database. I've implemented the search fuction which seems to work in my console. The problem is the php code which returns all the data in my db after I click on the search button. Is there anyway this can be solved?

How can i get php to return json array object from mysqli database? After result showing in postman, how can i search for a particular string and fetch for it in Android studio?

PHP code for fetching data

```
include "../auth/connect_db.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM staff_table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$staff = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $staff['search'][] = $row;
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($staff);
```

when webserver/getAllStaff.php?name=Boss

I would like to be able to also retrieve only the row this the details of the name or any other column string

Comment: You want to get results based on the search parameters you put?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what i want to do

Answer (score -1):

You are not receiving any post values that are coming from android. Then you are just selecting all the fields from your table which brings all the results. First Check for post values then change your sql statement and include the WHERE and LIKE clause in your sql statement. Something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['search'])){
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM staff_table where staff LIKE '%$value%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$staff = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 || !empty(mysqli_num_rows($result))){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $staff['search'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($staff);
}
else{
    $response["msg"] = "no results found";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
     //required post params is missing
    $response["msg"] = "Required paramaters missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: It still returns all the json objects instead of the particular row this the string i'm looking for

Comment: Thank you. I've still got the error from postman. What I'm trying to do is to return all my json object first. which is pointed to my recycler view in android and then from android, I want to be able to search for a particular object containing a string.. My Android code is working as tested but I've still got problems with the php code. As at not it doesn't return the object nor returns an object after posting the key and value. Do u get what I mean?

Comment: What does this line do? `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 || !empty(mysqli_num_rows($result)))`